# If $f$ is $C^{\infty}$ and $f^2$ is analytic, then $f$ is analytic.

Tags: complex-analysis, several-complex-variables

Assume that $f:\mathbb{C}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ is a $C^{\infty}$ function such that $f^2$ is (complex) analytic. Then show that $f$ is analytic.

Now, when we consider the question for functions in some [quasi-analytic Denjoy-Carleman class](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasi-analytic_function) some proofs I have seen don't carry over:

**Question:** If $f^2$ is a function in some [quasi-analytic Denjoy-Carleman class](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasi-analytic_function), then $f$ is quasi-analytic belonging to the same class?

Weierstrass preparation theorem doesn't hold in quasi-analytic Denjoy-Carleman classes, and it is an open problem whether a $C^\infty$ function that belongs to a quasi-analytic Denjoy-Carleman class along every line belongs to that class. Two of the proofs I have seen for the first problem break down for quasi-analytic functions for this reason.

Another open question in Denjoy-Carleman classes is about whether ideals are closed. For principal ideals this is related to solving for $f$ in $gf=h$, where $g$ and $h$ are known to belong to the Denjoy-Carleman class. The ideal generated by $g$ would not be closed if we can find a smooth $f$ that doesn't belong to the class such that it gets pushed into the class by the multiplication by $g$. In this way, the question above is about understanding whether a smooth function, not in the class, can be pushed into the class by multiplying by itself. If the square appears composed with $f$ on the other side then it is known to occur. This is, $f(x^2)$ may be in a quasi-analytic Denjoy-Carleman class while $f$ is not.

Comment: I assume $f^2$ here means $z\mapsto f(z)^2$ and not $f\circ f$? And also, what are your thoughts? What did you try?

Comment: $\overline{\overline{z}}=z$. So, yes.

Comment: Ah, I hadn't noticed the multiple variables. So $f\circ f$ wouldn't make any sense. I assume you don't have any trouble dealing with points where $f(z)\ne0$, right? So we only need to worry about neighbourhoods of the zeroes of $f$?

Comment: Solve it first for $n=1$. That may give you an idea for the general case.

Comment: Well, for $n=1$ it is quite easy: When you follow a small circle around a zero, which I place at the origin for convenience, $f(z)^2$ most travel around the origin an even number of times, or else the square root would flip its sign after one round. It follows that $f(z)^2=z^{2k}g(z)$ where $g(0)\ne0$. But then $f(z)=z^k\sqrt{g(z)}$ for a suitable (continuous) choice of branch of the square root. This idea does not seem to generalize to $n$ variables, however.

Comment: The role of $z^k$ in that proof is to be a polynomial that captures the vanishing of $f$. In several variables that role is played by the corresponding Weierstrass polynomial in the Weierstrass preparation theorem.

Comment: Well, it's been too long since I played with several complex variables, and I never did serious work with them. So I'll leave this for others now. You do seem to have a decent handle on it yourself.

Comment: if the OP is not really interested in the analytic case maybe the title should reflect that

Comment: Did I get the wrong impression then? Dont you know how to solve the analytic case?

Comment: Dear ABC: There is no need to be rude to people (like clark) who are trying to make your question more focused.

Comment: Since when knowing how to solve a problem makes it unimportant to find new proofs? New solutions for the first part could give an idea of how to attack the second part. Counting the one below I have got 3 or 4 different proofs, all breaking down for quasi-analytic functions for different reasons each. One of them stopping at an open problem about quasi-analytic functions.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the answer to your first question; I do not know anything about quasi-analytic functions to provide further input.

It suffices to consider the case where $f$ is not constant. Set $g=f^2$. Consider the subset $Z=f^{-1}(0)$. Then $Z=g^{-1}(0)$ as well. Since $g$ is assumed to be complex-analytic (this is my reading of your question), $Z$ is a proper analytic subvariety in ${\mathbb C}^n$. On the other hand, on $U= {\mathbb C}^n\setminus Z$ the multivalued function $\sqrt{g}$ is complex-analytic on $U$.  The function $f$ is (locally on $U$) a branch of $\sqrt{g}$; hence, $f$ is complex-analytic on $U$. Since $f$ extends continuously to $Z$, it is complex-analytic on the entire ${\mathbb C}^n$ by the [Riemann's removable singularity theorem in several variables](http://planetmath.org/riemannsremovablesingularitytheoreminseveralvariables).

Comment: Thanks. Yes, the proof that I have, and the ones I have been told so far, interestingly all break down for quasi-analytic functions.